# How do i add the Menu controller to any UiViewController , other than the rootview?

Tags: cosmicmind

I am trying just to display the floating Menu on a separate view controller that is not the rootview ? Normally i just add it to the rootview controller.

let menuController = AppMenuController(rootViewController: toolbarController)

```
    let navigationController  = AppNavigationDrawerController(rootViewController: menuController, leftViewController: leftViewController,rightViewController: rightViewController)
    let statusController = AppStatusBarController(rootViewController: navigationController)

    window = UIWindow(frame: Screen.bounds)

    window!.rootViewController = statusController

    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: Share more information and what you have tried till now.

Comment: I have only ever added it to the rootview contoller

Answer (score 0):

let main: MainViewController = {
return UIStoryboard.viewController(identifier: "MainViewController") as! MainViewController}()

let newView = AppMenuController(rootViewController: main)

self.present(allergyView, animated: false, completion: nil)

Answer (score 0):

Add the `Menu` as a property of the UIViewController. For example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    fileprivate let menu = Menu()
    fileprivate let baseSize = CGSize(width: 64, height: 64)

    open override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() {
        prepareMenu()
    }
}

extension MenuController {
    fileprivate func prepareMenu() {
        menu.zPosition = 1000
        menu.baseSize = baseSize

        view.layout(menu)
            .size(baseSize)
            .bottom(24)
            .right(24)
     }
}
```

In cases where you would not want to use the Material controllers with root view controllers, you should be able to look at the setup code in those controllers to see the code necessary to add the component they manage, for example MenuController.

All the best :)